# Amazon Music App loses state after a few hours

Tags: applications

I am listening to audio books on the Amazon Music app in the morning but when I pause at a specific chapter and want to resume in the evening, it displays the horizontal line symbolizing the progress in a song but no title of the album and the song. At this point I can only go back to the main menu and have to search for the album again and find the right chapter.

How can I the prevent Amazon Music app from losing state?

Comment: On Android apps can be terminated at any time (e.g. if other apps require more RAM). Apps can save their state before being terminated but it looks like Amazon Music app has some problems on saving or restoring the state.

Comment: This is a bug in Amazon Music app. The best thing to do is to report them through their preferred means of receiving bugs.